# Web.config redirect to page when going to site root

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, redirect, web-config

Web.config redirect to page when going to site root;

Perhaps a bit of an odd requirement but i need to redirect anyone going to the domain root to a given page, but only on the domain root.

for instance:

http://example.com redirects to http://example.com/page/details/5

however;

http://example.com/contact shouldnt be effected.

I can't find anything specific through google, though its possible im not understanding what im seeing..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just put a default.aspx page in the site root with the following code:

```
<script runat="server">
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Redirect("/page/details/5");
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty good way of doing things... i have no resolved the issue, so i will post an answer in a bit. Thanks though :D